# CRC Hamming distance, non-trivial real-world situation

Tags: coding-theory

The problem: I am co-developing a low-speed automation bus for low-cost hardware and need some error checking for its messages. Using a CRC for that seems to make sense, but which one?

I found [a paper by Koopman+Chakravarty](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/roses/dsn04/koopman04_crc_poly_embedded.pdf) but it doesn't say how they calculated the Hamming distances of the polynomials used.

One further complication is that our bus design affords three possible values I could use to calculate a CRC:

1. the actual binary message
2. the state of the $n$ bus wires at each time slot
3. as above, but XOR to the previous slot: cannot be zero

> Algorithm to encode a message: given $n$ wires there are $s=2^{n-1}$ possible states (one is excluded because it's identical to the previous one). Thus, treat the message as a bit stream, chunk it into 11-bit or 14-bit frames, treat each frame as an unsigned number, convert it to base $s$, add one to each digit, XOR each digit's binary value into the state of the wires, wait a couple of µsec, repeat. The receiver simply inverts this process.

I'd like to figure out how to achieve a maximum Hamming distance for $\le 100$-bit messages, with the least amount of overhead (i.e. a CRC-8 if possible), and I freely admit that I have more questions than answers at this point.

For instance, the XOR'd bus state has the interesting property that there are by definition no single-bit errors and no long runs of zeroes – does that affect the CRC's significance? how? Koopman+C. gives maximum Hamming distances for various "good" polynomials and block lengths, but one 1-bit error in the state of the hardware changes from 1 to ~10 bits in the resulting message: This obviously affects the CRC's end-to-end behaviour, but is it possible to select a polynomial so that it cannot result in a Hamming distance of 2?

> NB: 11- and 14- bit frames are used because they're at most 16 bits long (important for fast implementation on 8-bit CPUs) and have low overhead, i.e. $7^5$ is reasonably close to $2^{14}$ if the bus has three wires. Likewise, 11-bit blocks are used for 2-wire and 4-wire buses.

One brute-force approach would be to encode random messages, protect them with a couple of select CRCs, bomb them with 1…5 random bit errors, do this on a large multi-CPU machine for a week, and see at which point I find any false positives …

If anybody has a more efficient idea, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Is this more suitable for CS.Stackexchage?

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like some tailoring is required. I could not figure out what are the most typical error events? Single bit errors? Those you can detect easily with a CRC as long as its high enough degree. Do remember that EVERY CRC-polynomial will let some 2-bit error patterns through, if you use it for messages longer than the maximum block length. With an 8-bit CRC the maximum length of the protected data block cannot exceed 247.

Comment: But if, for example, a typical error event creates a burst of flipped bits, then you may need something else. A Reed-Solomon code could be one of the things to try. I didn't fully get what you said about XORing and adding one. Those operations don't always mesh well, and may produce unexpected things for the purposes of error protection (if for no other reason that "adding one" may affect an unpredictable number of bits due to carry). Caveat: this is mostly idle speculation.

Comment: I don't agree with Klangen that this would be a better fit for CSTheory. We do have a StackExchange dedicated to DSP, and that might be closer to the mark.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I coded up a message error simulator. The result is that "a single fault can flip multiple bits" is a seriously bad idea when you're using a CRC; I was able to quickly find a vector where a single affected bit still generated a correct 16-bit CRC (for 3+ wires, otherwise it takes two), due to the fun way I'm mutilating the state of said wires back into a message.

The fact that a modern CPU can do this test roughly 300'000 times a second (per core) does help here …

Comment: Yeah. Until you have a more realistic model of the type of errors that occur, a simulation is a very good idea :-)